# C# Google Drive List Files

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am trying to integrate a windows service app with Google Drive. Interactive authentication will not work in this scenario. I have been looking through all the documentation on the web but still have not been able to get this to work.

When I call the service using the .net Client API the app just hangs on the Execute() command of the List request.

If I watch fiddler I see:
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
`Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate`
`Pragma: no-cache`
`Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT`
`Date: Thu, 07 Nov 2013 13:31:08 GMT`
`Content-Type: application/json`
`X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`
`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`
`X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block`
`Server: GSE`
`Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic`
`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`
`7f`
`{`
`"access_token" : "ya29.AHES6ZRUlkSmg43b4jTY6xkakf0WL3O-blnmp5D3sNoaMYY",`
`"token_type" : "Bearer",`
`"expires_in" : 3600`
`}`
`0`

But nothing else.

If I call the service using just a http request I get a response back of 401 Login Required.
If I watch fiddler all I see is the response of 401 not the request.

Code for the authentication is:

```
 var certificate = new X509Certificate2(sKeyPath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(sEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata, DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts }

           }.FromCertificate(certificate));


        // Create the service.
        service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "servauth"
        });
```

Code for the File List is here:

```
     //Using Google API
        FilesResource.ListRequest requestApi = service.Files.List();
        //Stops on this line
        var listFiles = requestApi.Execute();

        //Using webrequest
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files");
        request.Method = "GET";
        service.Authenticator.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);

        //Response here is 401
        WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: HttpWebRequest how to generate the Authorization token for getting drive files @PForsythe